Changing Home Timezone on lock screen
I have a Samsung Note 20 running Android 13 and Nova Launcher.  The lock screen shows the time.  If I am roaming, it shows two clocks.  Since I shifted countries, the home clock has not moved, it still shows the time for my original home.
Using a new Google account based in the new country has not fixed this.  Is there a setting "Home Timezone" somewhere, that I can change?

Possible dupe? How do I set the Home Time Zone that shows up on the Dual Clock?

@AndrewT. You are correct. Its a dup but didnt have the answer. I have added the answer there. And for the first time voted to close my own question
